# Lightweight table editor

Tags: software-recommendation, text-editor, editor

I am looking for something like *Sublime Text* for tables. That is, when it encounters something with table delimited values (for example), the columns should be displayed aligned.

*Excel*, *Calligra Sheets* or *LibreOffice Calc* are too heavy for me, I want simpler, lighter, faster and free alternatives.

**Update:** The suggestions so far include spreadsheet programs that are able to do plotting and calculations. This is fine, but is also kind of overkill for me. I just need to *edit* the table, and aligned display. In fact, if Sublime Text (or any text editor, like Gedit, Geany) had a plugin that displayed columns aligned, that would be enough (*perfect*) for me.

Comment: For a comparison of the four main alternatives see the table in [this German article](http://www.pro-linux.de/artikel/2/1654/5,zusammenfassung.html), e.g. RAM usage in the third row.

Answer (score 26):

I can recommend **Gnumeric**.
Gnumeric is an open-source spreadsheet program. Gnumeric is...

- Free: Gnumeric and its source code are available free of charge,
  licensed under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 or version 3.
- Fast: Gnumeric starts up quickly and handles large spreadsheets
  while remaining responsive.
- Accurate: A spreadsheet should calculate the right answer.
  Gnumeric's built-in functions and tools are accurate, as
  several researchers have found.

To install:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install gnumeric
```

[image: Gnumeric]

[image: Gnumeric screenshot with scatter plot]

Comment: This does not support CSV files.

Comment: @smcs, look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31723185/view-semicolon-separated-csv-files-in-gnumeric

Comment: Thanks! I count that as half-support. What I want is double click on the file -> done. The import dialoge drives you crazy after a while. "Modern CSV" seems good for that.

Comment: Good tool and runs ok with massive (15MB+) csv files, unlike excel and libre calc. I agree it is lacking proper double-click-to-open csv support.  Its possible to double click CSV but it uses default import settings which are often wrong. I think all it needs is a settings dialog when double clicking a file or a way to change the default import settings.

Comment: Gnumeric and Calc have pretty frumpy handling of csv and tsv files.

Comment: This has added 6MB just re-saving an Excel. Does not work for me :(

Comment: It definitely does not open CSV files when the CSV filename is passed as a command line argument. It also failed to import a CSV file that imported easily into Excel, Google Sheets, Libreoffice, and gnumeric. It gave an error about needing a 1-character escape character. When I typed something (\, I think) it said the "Indexes are out of range" or something like that. Sorry for the lack of precision--not enough time to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 14):

## pyspread

<sup>python FTW</sup>
[image: pyspread screenshot]

#### Description from [pyspread‘s homepage](https://manns.github.io/pyspread/)

Pyspread is a non-traditional spreadsheet application that is based on and written in the programming language [Python](http://www.python.org/).

The goal of pyspread is to be the most pythonic spreadsheet.

Pyspread expects Python expressions in its grid cells, which makes a spreadsheet specific language obsolete. Each cell returns a Python object that can be accessed from other cells. These objects can represent anything including lists or matrices.

Pyspread is free software. It is released under the [GPL v3](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html). You can find the sorce code at [github](https://github.com/manns/pyspread).

#### Installation

```
sudo apt install pyspread
```

Comment: Will it read ordinary text files (tab separated, csv, etc.)?

Comment: @becko Just tried successfully, you need to choose File → Import to open those, works like a charm. You can even choose the delimiter sign(s) to use like in LibreOffice.

Comment: It is unable to open `csv` format it supports its own `pyspread` aka. `.pys` format.

Comment: I also confirm it is unable to open CSVs: with a very small CSV it takes a while trying to open it, until I cancel it.

Answer (score 12):

If you are a user of (or at least familiar with) emacs (or vim), there is [org-mode](http://orgmode.org), which contain a simple integrated editor for tables.
However, it needs the tables to be in a specific format, where columns are separated by vertical bars (i.e. the pipe symbol '|').

You can also do simple calculations, and the integration into the editor allows you to use the sophisticated editing facilities of emacs/vim.

[image: emacs org-mode table example]

Documentation can be found on the [org-mode site](http://orgmode.org/guide/Tables.html#Tables), and a small introduction [on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fTJVLJd_gz0).

Comment: The required `|` is a deal breaker for me. I usually work with tab separated text files.

Comment: @becko Simply use it like so: `sed 's/<TAB>/|/g' filename | emacs | sed 's/|/<TAB>/g' > filename` You could even define a function `emacs` out of it and it will be as if `|` is only the way `emacs` represents your tab delimiters.

Comment: @dessert If the file has `|` originally, this command will replace them with tabs when I close emacs.

Comment: @becko Well then simply let the function (or a script) check for that.

Comment: @becko you just have to write a good script to handle it. These kinds of limitations are easily overcome.

Comment: @MarkYisri I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 10):

## VIM Table Mode

[image: VIM Table Mode screenshot]

#### Description from [github repo page](https://github.com/dhruvasagar/vim-table-mode)

An awesome automatic table creator & formatter allowing one to create neat tables as you type. The plugin is also able to [format existing content into a table](https://github.com/dhruvasagar/vim-table-mode#formatting-existing-content-into-a-table) which makes it possible to work with csv or other text files. To get an idea of its features there's a [youtube demonstration video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lVQ0VJY3ps).

#### Installation

See [github repo page](https://github.com/dhruvasagar/vim-table-mode#installation).

Answer (score 6):

## MacroCALC

<sup>Did you say lightweight?</sup>
[image: MacroCALC screenshot]

#### Description from [MacroCALC‘s homepage](http://www.freakout.de/#mc)

MacroCALC - "mc" or "321" is a powerful Lotus compatible character based spreadsheet that supports 100000 rows, 700 columns, 40 functions, 8 display formats, file linking, macro programming and user definable functions.

It is a curses-based console-program and needs **no graphical environment**.

It is fully integrated with [`nt`]`roff`, `units`, `man`, `awk`, `perl` and `sh`. As it should be in the UNIX environment, the program can act as a filter enabling users to use pipes to perform complex transformations on data streams. It contains a `C` programming interface as well as Lotus WKS and dBASE file support. MacroCALC‘s own file-format is **flat ASCII**, easy to understand and can therefore be directly manipulated with `awk`, `perl` or other standard UNIX tools, or even with editors like `vi`.

Furthermore MacroCALC is able to manage units: Like a scientist the program is aware of the rules for calculating units; so for instance if a "length" is divided a "time" it will show a "speed" result, and a "length" cannot be added to a "mass".

#### Installation

See [MacroCALC‘s homepage](http://www.freakout.de/#mc) for installation instructions. Tested on Lubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Interesting, but how old?

Comment: @RonJohn The website says “Last revised: 12. August 2013”. Why does that matter?

Comment: yes, the website.  But what about macrocalc?  (I ask to see whether it's bitrot-ware, too old for modern compiler versions.  See the answer regarding Siag Office: "may not be installable in current Ubuntu releases".)

Comment: @RonJohn “Tested on Lubuntu 16.04” means I successfully installed it on my Lubuntu 16.04 system and quickly tested the functionality, so yes, I'm positive it's not too old for an up-to-date compiler. As the installation of SIAG failed on my system, I added this comment there. Did you read the answers completely?

Comment: How could I have missed that... **three times**?  :sadcat:

Answer (score 4):

## Siag (Scheme In A Grid) Office

<sup>great piece of software, but may not be installable in current Ubuntu releases</sup>
[image]

#### Description from [Siag‘s Homepage](http://siag.nu) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siag_Office)

Siag Office is a tightly integrated free office package. It is known to be extremely light-weight, hence able to run on very old systems reasonably well, such as on i486 computers with 16MB RAM. Because it is kept light-weight, the software lacks many of the features of major office suites, like LibreOffice, Calligra Suite, or Microsoft Office. Siag Office is distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License and included in Damn Small Linux, a lightweight Linux distribution.

Also see [this article](https://www.linux.com/news/siag-office-far-pathetic).

#### Installation

Siag needs to be compiled from source
Download and compile these libraries :-

neXtaw
http://siag.nu/pub/neXtaw/neXtaw-0.15.1.tar.gz
Mowitz
http://siag.nu/pub/mowitz/Mowitz-0.3.1.tar.gz

After extract each library issue these command inside each one directory .

```
./config 
make 
sudo make install
```

Download latest [source code](http://siag.nu/pub/siag/) and follow above steps .

<del>after other libraries (`libgd2-xpm-dev libxmu-dev xaw3dg-dev` and the ones mentioned [here](http://siag.nu/getting.html)) were installed first, unfortunately wasn't able to compile it on Lubuntu 16.04, but I may not have tried hard enough. See [this article](https://www.linux.com/news/siag-office-far-pathetic) for more detailed installation instructions.</del>

Comment: This looks like 1995 and when you look at the dates of the changelog it is almost like that. Last update from 2006 and the one before from 2003... how can you say this is WIP ?

Comment: @RoVo Btw, for lightweight software what it looks like is not important whatsoever.

Comment: Aaah, Your answer is WIP, I thought that was related to the Software. Then it makes sense ;-)

Comment: If it will not connect to the internet or open files that come from the internet it will be okay to use software that is not maintained and just working. Otherwise I would not use it.

Comment: That's a blast from the past!!  :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Atom](https://atom.io/) code editor with [tablr](https://atom.io/packages/tablr) or [table-editor](https://atom.io/packages/table-editor) package.

Download .deb file of Atom from its [website](https://atom.io/). Then install it either by using GDebi Package Installer or by running following commands in terminal (one by one):

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then install **tablr** or **table-editor** package in Atom either by using in-built package installer (which is *Install* tab inside *Settings* View) inside Atom or by running the following commands respectively :-

```
apm install tablr
apm install table-editor
```

Answer (score 2):

## Sublime Table Editor

<sup>Who needs a new program when *Sublime* can perform the task?</sup>
[image: Sublime Table Editor screenshot cropped]

#### Description from [github repo page](https://github.com/vkocubinsky/SublimeTableEditor)

*Table Editor* is a package for the *Sublime Text 2* and *Sublime Text 3* editor for edit text tables. *Table Editor* is has almost the same keys as Emacs-org mode table editor. To get an idea of the features there's a [helpful article](http://brettterpstra.com/2015/04/22/sublime-text-tips-for-markdown-table-editing/) and these two videos: [video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HeIYib-QpbM) [video 2](https://vimeo.com/83939527)

Judging from what the github page says *Sublime Table Editor* is **not supported any more**, however the software may still be working. I didn't test it on my system though.

#### Installation

See [github repo page](https://github.com/vkocubinsky/SublimeTableEditor#installation).

Comment: I'm moving to Atom. Do you know if it exist somthing similar for Atom?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend `sc-im`, which stands for **s**preadsheet **c**alculator **im**proved. It is currently available on [Github](https://github.com/andmarti1424/sc-im) only.

It is actively developed and lean.

Features from the Github description:

---

Some of the features of SC-IM

- UNDO / REDO.
- 65.536 rows and 702 columns supported. (The number of rows can be expanded to 1.048.576 if wished).
- CSV / TAB delimited / XLSX file import and export.
- Scripting support with LUA. Also with triggers and c dynamic linked modules.
- Clipboard support.
- GNUPlot interaction.
- Key-mappings.
- Sort of rows.
- Filter of rows.
- Subtotals.
- Cell shifting.
- 256 color support - screen colors can be customized by user, even at runtime.
- Colorize cells or give them format such as bold or underline.
- Wide character support. The following alphabets are supported: English, Spanish, French, Italian, German, Portuguese, Russian, Ukrainian, Greek, Turkish, Czech, Japanese, Chinese.
- Autobackup.
- Implement external functions in the language you prefer and use them in SC-IM.
- Use SC-IM as a non-interactive calculator, reading its input from a external script.
- More movements commands implemented !
- Input and Output was completely rewritten.

About the name, the idea is that the program can be identified as another vim-like app. SC-IM stands for Spreadsheet Calculator Improvised. :-)

---

So commands and workflow are familiar if you have experience with `vi` or `vim`.

Some screenshots:

[image: Screenshot #1]

[image: Workflow SC-IM #1]
[image: Workflow SC-IM #2]
[image: Workflow SC-IM #3]

For installation, `build-essential`, `ml-yacc`, `bison` and the libraries `libncurses5-dev` and `libncurses5w-dev` are needed. Just run `make`, `sudo make install` in the `src` directory of `sc-im` after cloning from github.

Answer (score 2):

Setting elastic tab stop in jEdit looks good to me:

http://www.jedit.org/users-guide/indent.html

This feature makes the tab stop expand to the lines above and below.  I think this might only work with tabs but you could use replacement to replace your delimiter with a tab and then undo the replacement later.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Visidata is a great tool for your goal
https://www.visidata.org/

Answer (score 1):

## VS Code and Excel Viewer

A possible lightweight option if you are already using [VS code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is to use an extension such as [Excel Viewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GrapeCity.gc-excelviewer) which allows to look at CSV files with a tabular style:

[image]

#### Installation

Installing VS Code for this task is even more an overkill than using any spreadsheet software, but here are the
[instructions from the official manual](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux).
Once VS Code installed, simply follow the [instructions on the extension page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GrapeCity.gc-excelviewer).