# How can I plot data from sc in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, plot

Using the [sc](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/sc.1.html) (Spreadsheet Calculator) or (Spreadsheet Calculator Improvised) [sc-im](https://github.com/andmarti1424/sc-im/blob/freeze/Readme.md) ([more](https://askubuntu.com/a/964814/197910)) I can manage spreadsheets in the terminal.

Is there a way to plot this data in the terminal, too?

I've found [termgraph](https://github.com/mkaz/termgraph/blob/master/README.md), which allows to plot in the terminal, but it doesn't work with data from sc.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/964814/197910 shows sc-im will plot, but I don't know how. See the URL added to your question for a link to the home page of that package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to K7AAYs hint about the fact that sc-im does have plotting integrated, I figured out how to do this:

Press 'v' to enter visual mode and highlight the data, then enter ":plot bar" to plot the data as a bar graph. Using ":help" and searching for plot reveals this information. Other than 'bar', there's also 'line', 'scatter' and 'pie'.